# Retrieving only half the Image when converting to Base64

Tags: c#, arrays, encoding, upload

I have an API which reads an uploaded Image and changes it to a `byte[]`, however in the database the field for where I have to save the image is a string instead of `varbinary(MAX)`, and I cannot change the field type of the database.

I thought about converting the image to base64 and then storing it but this might cause unnecessary strain on the database.

I have found online the following way but this method can be inconsistent based on the server as the encoding might change:

```
var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(result);
```

And if I were to use the above method I would need to know what type of encoding does `ReadBytes` use.

Below is my code:

```
byte[] fileData = null;
using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(image.InputStream))
{
      binaryReader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
      fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(image.ContentLength);
}
```

Furthermore, when I converted the image to a base64 and viewed it, only half the image was visible:

```
var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(fileData);
```

Comment: If you don't create the BinaryReader with a Encoding UTF-8 will be used as default as mentioned in the documentation. You should think about encoding your image like you said (base64). An image is a stream of bytes where all bytes are valid. You might hit an invalid byte for the encoding your database uses for that column and the database might be trying to "fix" that and breaks your image when storing in the database.

Comment: Why would base64 cause strain on the server?

Comment: You can't just convert a byte array to a string. Converting to Base64 is an option, but like you hint at, it will take a lot more storage space. Saying you can't fix the database isn't really a good starting point. You absolutely need to fix that before thinking about code.

Comment: Fixing the database should be the way to go, it's easier and more efficient, but I am not allowed to change the database structure and the client requested to save the image directly in the database instead of saving it in a folder somewhere as it is safer that way.

Answer (score 2):

use Convert.toBase64String() method or just using MemoryStream class->

```cs
// 1.toBase64String()
string str = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
// 2.MemoryStream class
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the BinaryReader with this overload that specifies the encoding.

```
var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(System.IO.Stream input, System.Text.Encoding encoding);
```